# unable to store string in a file in php

Tags: php, forms

I am pretty much new to PHP
I have just created a form in my html page

```
<form action="http://localhost/practise.php" method="POST">
        <b>Code</b>
        <textarea id="Code" name ="mycode" > 
        </textarea>
        <input type="submit">
</form>
```

in my practise.php file I have written the following code:

```
$code = $_POST['mycode'];
echo $code;
$path = "/home/User/Desktop/test.c";
$myfile = fopen($path, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $code);
fclose($myfile);
echo "SucceessFul!!";
```

I am able to get the content which I have typed in my form 
but along with it I get "Unable to open file"

```
echo file_put_contents($path,"Hello World. Testing!");
```

i tried using file_put_contents which returns the number of character written into the file on success, or FALSE on failure.
but in my case  i just don't see any output on using file_put_contents
i tried to change the location of my file
but i still get the same error
I am currently using Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

Comment: does your webserver userID have access to that directory?  Almost certainly not...

Comment: Make sure the /home/User/Desktop folder is writeable by the apache user (usually www-data in ubuntu).

Comment: can you please tell me how to check if my web server has access to that directory???

Comment: i tried to use chgrp www-data /home/user/Desktop
but I get "changing group of /home/user/Desktop is not permitted" @MarcB

Comment: doesn't matter. you need to allow Apache access to ALL of the directories in the path. changing `Desktop` is pointless if Apache can't get into `user` to begin with. e.g. "here's a free pile of money, but it's inside a locked bank vault".

Comment: i tried to create a directory in the root itself by using this command
"mkdir abcd && chgrp www-data abcd"
but i still get the same error @MarcB

Comment: Go to the parent directory (/home/User) and type "ls -l". This will give you something like "drwxrwxr-x 12 user1 user2" next to the folder name. If "user1" or "user2" are the apache user then they have permission. You can change the folders permissions using the chown or chgrp linux commands but I would read up on linux permissions before you start messing about with them.

Comment: Also you need superuser access to change permissions for any user that isn't your own, by putting "sudo" in front of the command.

Comment: thanks a lot dk80 and MarcB
i used the following commands ti get the permission
sudo chgrp www-data /home/User/Desktop/test.c and
sudo chmod g+w /home/srikanth/Desktop/test.c
and now i am able to write to my file